# Text files edit C

Tags: c, file, edit

I have a program which takes data(int,floats and strings) given by the user and writes it in a text file.Now I have to update a part of that written data.

For example:

At line 4 in file I want to change the first 2 words (there's an `int` and a `float`). How can I do that?

With the information I found out, `fseek()` and `fputs()` can be used but I don't know exactly how to get to a specific line.

(Explained code will be appreciated as I'm a starter in C)

Comment: Can you change the format of that data file? Did you consider JSON or perhaps YAML? There are several JSON parsers in C eg jansson

Answer (score 4):

You can't "insert" characters in a file. You will have to create program, which will read whole file, then copy part before insert to a new file, your edition, rest of file.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to read all the file, and ignore what is not needed.

`fseek` is not really useful: it positions the file at some byte offset (relative to the start or the end of the file) and don't know about line boundaries.

Actually, lines inside a file are an ill defined concept. Often a line is a sequence of bytes (different from the newline character) ended by a newline (`'\n'`). Some operating systems (Windows, MacOSX) read in a special manner text files (e.g. the real file contains `\r\n` to end each line, but the C library gives you the illusion that you have read `\n`).

In practice, you probably want to use [line input routines](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html) notably `getline` (or perhaps `fgets`).

<sup>if you use `getline` you should care about `free`-ing the line buffer.</sup>

If your textual file has a very regular structure, you might `fscanf` the data (ignoring what you need to skip) without caring about line boundaries.

If you wanted to absolutely use `fseek` (which is a mistake), you would have to read the file twice: a first time to remember where each line starts (or ends) and a second time to `fseek` to the line start. Still, that does not work for updates, because you cannot insert bytes in the middle of a file.

And in practice, the most costly operation is the actual disk read. Buffering (partly done by the kernel and `<stdio.h>` functions, and partly by you when you deal with lines) is negligible.

Of course you cannot change in place some line in a file. If you need to do that, process the file for input, produce some output file (containing the modified input) and rename that when finished.

BTW, you might perhaps be interested in indexed files like [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) etc...  or even in databases like [SqlLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), [MariaDb](https://mariadb.org/), [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/) etc.... and you might be interested in standard textual serialization formats like [JSON](http://json.org) or [YAML](http://yaml.org/) (both have many libraries, even for C, to deal with them).

Answer (score 0):

`fseek()` is used for random-access files where each record of data has the same size. Typically the data is binary, not text.

To solve your particular issue, you will need to read one line at a time to find the line you want to change. A simple solution to make the change is to write these lines to a temporary file, write the changes to the same temporary file, then skip the parts from the original file that you want to change and copy the reset to the temporary file. Finally, close the original file, copy the temporary file to it, and delete the temporary file.

With that said, I suggest that you learn more about random-access files. These are very useful when storing records all of the same size. If you have control over creating the orignal file, these might be better for your current purpose.

Comment: I am not entirely sure that random-access binary file is always a good answer. They certainly bring their own burden: non-portability of the data (unless you care a big lot about some architecture-neutral serialization format), nearly uneditable by humans, brittleness, etc...